# SqlBulkCopy in SQLCLR stored procedure?

Tags: c#, .net, sql, sqlclr

I created SQLCLR stored procedure that retrieve large amount of data from external service.
Can I bulk copy the data to a new table in the same SQLCLR stored procedure?

Answer (score 1):

I'll zoom out here to the general problem of how to expose data from a service inside SQL. What can might do is rewrite your stored procedure as a [Table Valued CLR function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131103.aspx) that streams the results. Then you can use like this:

```
insert into MyTable(id, name)
select id, name from dbo.MyTableFunc(agrs)
```

The infrastructure for this is well optimized, I used it and was quickly able to get it to some 3k rows per second when I stopped optimizing, and the bottleneck was in getting the rows over the network.

The upside of exposing the service as a function is that you also directly use it in queries and joins, no need to store it in to a table on disk first (extra step with slow disks, transaction log, locks yadayada). It also cancels gracefully and you can do `top 100` etc.

If you tell us more/ give some code we can help more.

Comment: Actually, my first try was using CLR table-UDF for the same reasons you mentioned. But I had a problem, I needed the ability to project only some of the columns and UDF have predefined schema.
So, I tried solving it with a UDF that return the key columns and XML column containing the additional columns I wanted to project. But it made the sqlclr radically slower because of the xml serialization so I changed it to using stored procedure.
Right now, I'm using stored procedure without sqlbulkcopy (simple transcation) and it works fairly well, but it will probably be a problem for 1m+ rows.